# Mass Link Checker

Tags: c#

The following code reads a CSV file for image links and checks the links for 200 or 404. The CSV file contains a **sku,image url** per line. I believe the code works fine however it appears that it may be returning false positives when dealing with a larger CSV file (Ex: 500k+ rows), how can I improve my code? I am more worried about accuracy rather than speed however both are important. Your comments and suggestions are appreciated!

Program Class:

```
var reader = File.ReadLines(@"C:\product_active.csv");
var check = new ImageCheck();
var times = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3};

 Parallel.ForEach(reader, times, x =>
            //foreach (var x in reader)
        {
            var y = x.Split(',');
            var newURL = "";
            if (!y[1].Contains("http://"))
            {
                newURL = "http://addurl.com/" + y[1];
                Console.WriteLine(newURL);
            }
            else
            {
                newURL = y[1];
            }
            switch (check.URL(newURL))
            {
                case true:
                    Console.WriteLine(y[0] + " is good!");
                    break;
                case false:
                    Console.WriteLine(y[0] + " is bad!");
                    break;
            }
        });
```

ImageCheck Class:

```
public bool URL(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "Get";
            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            response.Close();
            return true; //(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you making a lot of assumptions about your data,   you're under the assumption that you csv has no empty rows, and contains at least 1 comma. y[1] this could blow up, instead of handling the request.  2 why are you using a switch case on your check.URL

Comment: My assumptions are correct. This data is exported directly from a database. As for why am I using a switch case, I don't really have an answer but I figured it would work :/

Comment: switches should be used for 3 or more senarios you can change that directly to an if,  I noticed you're explicitly checking for http:// what would happen if it was https://

Comment: I was using an if statement before but the IDE was complaining about redundancy so I changed it to a switch but I will go back to an if statement if that is better practice. Also, no urls have https://.  The data in the csv is 'controlled': all rows are separated by a sku,image url if there is no http:// add a link which is a CDN link where the image should live and there are no empty rows.

Comment: IDEs don't always know what they are talking about  :)

Comment: Why do you think it is reporting  false positives? Actual test results or gut feeling?

Comment: Whenever you make assumptions and your code doesn't work, it might be useful to write some separate code that tests just your assumptions.

Comment: Or just grep "https:" foo.csv?

Comment: @cdkMoose I believe it is reporting false positives because there is more code that I have in which if ImageCheck returns false, execute a sql query to "deactivate" that sku. However after running this several times, skus with images that are clearly 404 are still "active".

Comment: @NuWin, is that extra code also running in parallel?  Reading/checking in parallel is more stable than updating in parallel.

Comment: @cdkMoose Yes it is, However let me rephrase, the extra code is not actually connecting to the database, rather it writes the update query statement to deactivate if 404 to a text file. Afterwards I will execute these queries manually. Although, doing this in parallel has resulted in minor errors though such as two update query ends up being in one line rather than individual lines but this is clearly visible and not a big deal.

Comment: Possible collisions on parallel writes to that file?  Tnen the later code wouldn't de-activate all of the 404s.

Comment: Is printing absolutely necessary? It may well be the bottleneck of your program. Could you store the results and print them on demand?

Comment: @cdkMoose Yes there could be potential collisions I suppose.

Comment: @Caridorc Printing the sql statements to a text file is not absolutely necessary. When you say store, do you mean adding them to a list/array then writing them after?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we require that your code be working as intended before posting it here. It's obvious from your question and comments that you don't believe your code is actually working. (And simply compiling and running without exceptions **does not** count as working.)

Comment: @NuWin Yes, that

Answer (score 4):

1. The names of you variables /methods could be improved to be more descriptive (e.g. x <-> line, y <-> record, ...)
2. You have some redunatant code that can be removed (the if/else) and the switch stament).
3. In case of exceptions you `HttpWebResponse` is not disposed.
4. You dont have to set the verb "GET" because it is the default.
5. The Method URL can be static
6. The code that checks if the URL is valid could be moved in a separate method
7. The `Contains` should be a `StartWith` that ignores cases.

That would change your code to something like that:

```
var reader = File.ReadLines(@"C:\product_active.csv");
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };

Parallel.ForEach(reader, options, line =>
{
    var record = line.Split(',');
    if (record.Length < 2)
        return; // or throw an exception

    var key = record[0];
    var url = record[1].Trim(' ');  

    url = EnsureUrlIsValid(url);

    var isStatusOK = IsHttpStatusOk(url);
    var statusMessage = isStatusOK ? " is good!" : " is bad!";
    Console.WriteLine(key + statusMessage);
});

public static string EnsureUrlIsValid(string url)
{
    if (!url.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        url = "http://addurl.com/" + url;
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }
    return url;
}

public static bool IsHttpStatusOk(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse()) 
            return (response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could replace the url check by using [Uri.TryCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572(v=vs.110).aspx) or just [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring(v=vs.110).aspx) [not sure about this one]